# Can I be assured that MSIEXEC is available on a stock Windows platform?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I need to use MSIEXEC to extract contents of an MSI package (without installing it) and do it from a local service, but the question I have is whether MSIEXEC is available on all stock OS's since Windows XP SP3, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `MSIExec` is available in most of the recent versions of WIndows Installer (3.0 and up), and there are other command line options available for earlier version. This seems to indicate that `MSIExec` has been around for several versions of the installer, which would by necessity include XP SP3 and later.

Checking on a clean install of Windows XP SP3 Virtual Mode on Windows 7 Pro, it has MSIExec installed for Windows Installer 3.0. It's also in Win7 Professional.

Comment: Indeed.  "Windows Installer 3.0 is included in Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2)."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: However, I'm not sure whether or not version 3.0 can necessarily extract the contents of a package meant for a later version.  It would probably be a good idea to test this with the specific package in question.

Comment: Thank you, both. Actually according to the link posted above I can expect Windows Installer 4.5, on XP SP3.

Comment: I don't think so.  IIRC SP3 did not introduce a new version of Windows Installer, so a new installation of XP SP3 (with no updates or additional software) will only have Windows Installer 3.0.

Comment: But it says this in the link you posted: "Windows Installer 4.5 requires Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2) and later, and Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later."

Comment: @user843732: What you quoted says "Windows Installer 4.5 requires", not "Windows XP with Service Pack 2 includes Windows Installer 4.5". IOW, Windows Installer 4.5 will only install on XP SP2 or higher; it says nothing about 4.5 being included in XP SP2. Your question was about the existence of `MSIExec`, not when specific functionality in `MSIExec` existed. (They're not the same thing.) If you have specific questions related to that functionality, ask a new question (or use the MSDN links to find the information based on the functionality you need to support).